# Не удалось найти часть пути

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма, на ней treeview и textbox.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на элемент в treeview, должен выводиться текст который берется из файла, а сам файл находится в папке(Gloss) с приложением.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```
if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Index == 0)
            {
                materialMultiLineTextBox1.Text = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + File.ReadAllText(@"\Gloss\B.txt");
            }
```

Но выходит ошибка: "Не удалось найти часть пути "C:\Gloss\B.txt"."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... = File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Gloss\B.txt");
```